# Nested fragments are not working on back click in xamarin android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-fragments, xamarin.android

I have created one activity and 2 fragments. **Fragment B is inside Fragment A**. When I click on back button on my phone **it doesn't go to Fragment A from Fragment B**. But it crashes the app. I am maintaining a Stack.

```
public void ShowFragment(SupportFragment fragment)
        {
            if (fragment.IsVisible)
            {
                return;
            }
            Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentTransaction trans = SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
            fragment.View.BringToFront(); 
            trans.Hide(mCurrentFragment);
            Console.WriteLine("Hiding fragemnt current " + mCurrentFragment.Tag+" fragment "+fragment.Tag);
            trans.Show(fragment);
        
            if (mStackFragments.Count != 0)
            {
                SupportFragment sf = mStackFragments.Pop();
                if (fragment != sf)
                {
                    mStackFragments.Push(sf);
                    mStackFragments.Push(fragment);
                }
                else
                {
                    mStackFragments.Push(sf);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                mStackFragments.Push(fragment);
            }
            mCurrentFragment = fragment;
            trans.Commit();
            LoadFragmentTitleTxtView();
            LoadActionBarSpinner();
        }
```

above method is used to show the fragment/main screen, whereas the following code is for OnBackPressed.

```
public override void OnBackPressed()
        {
            if (mDrawerLayout.IsDrawerOpen((int)GravityFlags.Left))
            {
                mDrawerLayout.CloseDrawer((int)GravityFlags.Left);
            }
            else
            {
                if (mStackFragments.Count > 1)
                {
                    //mStackFragments.Pop();
                    Console.WriteLine("Popping 1st " + mStackFragments.Pop().Tag+" Count "+mStackFragments.Count);
                    SupportFragment frag = mStackFragments.Pop();
                    Console.WriteLine("Poppoing 2nd " + frag.Tag+" Count "+mStackFragments.Count);
                    if (frag == chaptersFragment)
                    {
                        if (chapterfiltertext != "")
                        {
                            item.ExpandActionView();
                            sssearchview.SetQuery(chapterfiltertext, false);
                            mainview.Animate().Alpha(1f).SetListener(null);
                        }
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("In back method.. "+frag.Tag);
                    ShowFragment(frag);
                }
                else
                {
                    Finish();
                }
            }
        }
```

its working fine for the fragments which doesn't have any nested fragments within them.

This is the code for the nested **fragment B** to load it on main screen **from fragment A**.

```
FragmentTransaction tx = context.SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
            FragmentB fragmentB = new FragmentB();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.PutString("letter", tmp1);
            fragmentB.Arguments = args;
            tx.Replace(Resource.Id.main, fragmentB, "innerDictFrag");
            tx.AddToBackStack(null);
            context.mStackFragments.Push(fragmentB);
            tx.Commit();
```

Comment: Can you provide your sample at github, then I will download your sample to test.

Comment: at ```fragment.View.BringToFront();``` says **System.NullReferenceException:** 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: **SupportFragment frag = mStackFragments.Pop();**, the frag value is null or other?

Comment: it is not null. its popping out the fragment.

Comment: If you didn't resolve your problem, you can provide one sample sample that reproduce your question at gtihub, I will test at my side.

Comment: No thanks, I have resolved the problem. By not using the method that I was using before. Now everything is fine. thanks for your time.